# iMacros javascript loop on condition

Tags: javascript, while-loop, imacros

The task is to change proxy, open a site (for example youtube.com), check if the logo is present. If there is no logo, than do it once again (change proxy and open youtube.com). If the logo is present, than paste some words in the search form.
But the problem is that the section of code from "do" to "while" doesn't work correctly. It doesn't open the url and just goes into infinite loop...

**UPD1**

I made some changes in my code and it works but the problem is that it resets the proxy after "macro" code has finished. When "macro1" code is in process the proxy address is not set.

**UPD2**

I tried to add "n2" variable, store "n" value in it and set proxy once again in "macro1" but "n2" always takes value "1". Don't know how to make it store the value from the "do while" code.

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:";
//var extracted = iimGetLastExtract();
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE c:\\proxy.txt" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{n}}" + "\n";
macro +=  "CLEAR" + "\n";
macro +=  "PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
macro +=  "URL GOTO=https://www.youtube.com/" + "\n";
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:logo EXTRACT=HREF" + "\n";

var macro1;
macro1 = "CODE:";   
macro1 +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE c:\\address.txt" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !ERRORCONTINUE YES" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=ID:gs_tti50 CONTENT={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE c:\\proxy.txt" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{n}}" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
macro1 +=  "pause" + "\n";

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
    var n = 1
    do
        {
        iimSet("n",n)
        iimPlay(macro);

        var ret = iimGetLastExtract();
        if(ret == "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif")
            {
            break;
            }
        n++;
        } while(true)


    iimSet("n",n);
    iimPlay(macro1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redid your code. Test it and give us feedback.

```
var macro1;

macro1 = "CODE:";
macro1 += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro1 += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n";
macro1 += "SET !DATASOURCE c:\\proxy.txt" + "\n";
macro1 += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
macro1 += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
macro1 += "CLEAR" + "\n";
macro1 += "PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
macro1 += "URL GOTO=https://www.youtube.com/" + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:logo EXTRACT=HREF" + "\n";

var macro2;

macro2 = "CODE:";
macro2 += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro2 += "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE c:\\search_words.txt" + "\n";
macro2 += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
macro2 += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
macro2 += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro2 += "SET !ERRORCONTINUE YES" + "\n";
macro2 += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
macro2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=ID:gs_tti50 CONTENT={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
macro2 += "pause" + "\n";

var limit = prompt("How many loops you want to do.", 10);

limit = parseInt(limit);

var proxy_counter = 1;

for (i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {

    //open youtube and extract logo link
    iimSet("i", proxy_counter)
    iimPlay(macro1);

    var extracted = iimGetLastExtract();

    //if the logo link is present then fill search box
    //if not then go to next loop, change proxy, open yt and start over
    if (extracted != "#EANF#") {
        iimSet("i", i)
        iimPlay(macro2);
    } else {
        proxy_counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your work but "macro1" code just goes into loop and "macro2" code is not executed.
P.S.
I have updated my code but there is still a problem.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: This can mean that there was no logo on the page. I also removed the set loop part of the code. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Thanks. This code works fine (as well as your previous code) if change "macro1" to "macro2" in the "if" block. But it has the same problem as mine. When "macro2" code runs proxy settings are reseted...

Comment: And you don't want it to be reseted? I will update the code now. I inserted another counter that changes if the macro2 is not played.

Comment: No, I don't want proxy to be reseted when the "macro2" code works. There are situations when one proxy doesn't work and I want another proxy to be set before "macro2" code starts. Sorry but in this code the proxy is still blank when `macro2 += "pause" + "\n";` code works.

Comment: You can make what you want from the code you've got.